# Putting 2 WHERE statements together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having problems putting two where statements together

My current code:

```
include 'config.php'; 

$result22 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='".$_SESSION['username']."'     AND to_read_yet='yes' ");


$num_rows22 = mysql_num_rows($result22);


echo "$num_rows22 ";
```

For some reason this isn't working. I am not getting any results i have checked the db and there are results which should come out

Comment: You have a syntax error in the first place: the double quotes around the word *no*.

Comment: This is what you get ...  Developers, especially web developers, assume that they do not need to learn SQL. Please. For your own good, @nickkdavies, get some book on MySQL. And when you are done with it - read [SQM Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

Comment: It seems to me that the question has been changed quite substantially from the initial question. If you feel that the original question has been answered (which I think it has), perhaps you should accept an answer and ask a new question?

Comment: I have :D picked the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about sql syntax. After where you put any number conditions with bool operators. Using 2 times `where` is incorrect

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='".$_SESSION['username']."'     AND to_read_yet='"no"' ");
```

Comment: Thanks the code worked was my own fault for copying and pasting wrong LOL

Answer (score 3):

Leave the second WHERE expression out, it's just WHERE condition_1 AND condition_2 AND condition_3 AND ....

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND to_read_yet='"no"' ");
```

Comment: For some resson its not getting any results will change the top bit of code to show the full code now

Comment: I'm not really familiar with PHP, but shouldn't it be `ECHO $Result22` instead of `ECHO "Result22"` ? Without the quotes around `$Result22?`

Have you tried to run the command in your database management system? see if it works there?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE to_user = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
  AND to_read_yet= '"no"'
```

Comment: For some resson its not getting any results will change the top bit of code to show the full code now

Comment: Did you try this query in your DB shell ?

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='".$_SESSION['username']."'     AND to_read_yet='no' ");
```

Comment: For some resson its not getting any results will change the top bit of code to show the full code now

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' AND to_read_yet='no'" );
```

Drop the second `WHERE`

Comment: For some resson its not getting any results will change the top bit of code to show the full code now